# Creating a light sweep effect (shiny) on an image (logo)

Tags: css, effects

I would like to add a light sweep effect to an image, to looks like is shining.

Desired behavior: [image]
(like in this image, but the image, but the light moving)

I found some solutions that do exactly what I was expecting but only on div elements. I tried to apply with images but no success.
Is there any idea how to add a shiny effect on a PNG image?
`Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nqQc7/289/`

Comment: What happens when you apply the class to the `img` tag? You said it doesn't work, what happens?

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://codepen.io/nw/pen/GqBzJ

Comment: @mlegg yes, very similar! but I wanted to add the same effect on a logo (like every 5-10 seconds) to simulate a light movement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `img` tag doesn't like pseudo elements, you'll need to use a wrapper element and `absolute`ly position your `img` within it. Something like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nqQc7/630/) shows, so shown below:

```css
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap:before {
  content: "";
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200%;
  width: 200%;
  top: -120%;
  left: -120%;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 45%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 55%, transparent 100%);
  transition: all 2s;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  animation: shine 6s infinite forwards;
}
@keyframes shine {
  0% {
    top: -120%;
    left: -120%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 100%;
    top: 100%;
  }
  40% {
    left: 100%;
    top: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200" />
  <div>
```